# Splitting string in tuple

Tags: python, split, tuples

I have a tuple of string and I am trying to split the string so that when I search for the ingredient peanuts it will print out (300.0, 'g')

```
    recipe = ('peanut butter', '300 g peanuts,0.5 tsp salt,2 tsp oil')
```

What I want to achieve

```
    get_ingredient_amount('peanuts', recipe)
    prints  --> (300.0, 'g')
```

What I did

```
    def get_ingredient_amount(recipe):
        for idx, (x, y,z) in enumerate(recipe):
             recipe[idx] = (float(x), str(y), str(z))
             return recipe
```

**Erorr received
ValueError: too many values to unpack **

Comment: What is the structure of `recipe` supposed to be? It's not clear what format you're storing information in.

Comment: `recipe` is a tuple of two strings: `"peanut butter"` and `"300 g peanuts,0.5 tsp salt,2 tsp oil"`.  It is not a tuple of four strings as you seem to think.

Comment: @JohnGordon or the OP forgot to add ```'``` before and after the ```,```  Which is what I think they should do to fix this.   though, I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try my function to get the value of the ingredient you want. Note that your format must be like in your example

```
def get_ingredient_amount(ingredient_name, recipe):
    for item in recipe[1].split(','):
        if ingredient_name in item:
            amount, unit = item.split()[:2]
            return float(amount), unit
    return None


recipe = ('peanut butter', '300 g peanuts,0.5 tsp salt,2 tsp oil')
result_peanuts = get_ingredient_amount('peanuts', recipe)
result_salt = get_ingredient_amount('salt', recipe)

print(result_peanuts) #(300.0, 'g')
print(result_salt) #(0.5, 'tsp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like using tuple for recipe is a poor design, since you don't know how many items are actually in your recipe. I will use dictionary instead.

```
peanut_butter_recipe = {"peanut" : "300 g",
                        "salt" : "0.5 tsp",
                        "oil" : "2 tsp"}

print(peanut_butter_recipe["peanut"]) # print 300 g
```

If you have to use tuple, then I will agree with Hoang Minh Quang's answer.